# Revert branch or merge revert from trunk?

Tags: svn, branch, revert

Is there a commonly accepted practice on how to propagate a revert from trunk to test/stage and production branches?

My scenario should be quite common:

- rev 1 start test branch
- rev 2 start prod branch
- rev 3 commit change to trunk
- rev 4 merge trunk to test
- rev 5 revert trunk to rev 1

Would I now

a) merge trunk to test

or

b) revert test to rev 1

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "commonly accepted", but since it doesn't matter, for simplicity, I personally would want my test branch rev to be no further from the main rev than necessary, so I would merge trunk to test.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. As you said it comes naturally that you'd want to propagate changes always in the same manner. I just wanted to be sure not to miss any point.